# Accessing pip packages from Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I recently updated my macOS version and had to reinstall Anaconda.  I had always tried to install packages via `pip` so that they would be accessible whether using Anaconda (Spyder, specifically) or executing files in the terminal (without Anaconda, e.g. `python myfile.py`).  However, after the reinstall, it looks like Anaconda is unable to access packages that are installed through `pip` but not through `conda`.

I'm aware that I can activate a given environment in Anaconda and then use `pip` to install packages for that environment, but I'm looking for global access to packages so that I don't have to install packages multiple times.

Is there a workaround to so that `pip` packages can be accessed universally?

EDIT:  When I installed Python 3 on macOS, I followed the guide here:  https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac#what-to-do.

Comment: are you using same python version ?

Comment: Yes, I can run `pip --version`, which shows this: `/Users/myusername/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`.  Then in Spyder I run `sys.version`, which also shows `3.8.3`.  If it helps, this is the guide I followed to make sure I was using Python 3 rather than 2:  https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac#what-to-do

Comment: Try `conda install pip` (once) and then `pip install <package>`. See "Installing non-conda packages" in https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html.

Comment: if you followed this tuto its right. maybe you had to export modules from previous conda env and import it on new one.

Comment: I tried uninstalling the package, running `conda install pip` and then reinstalling and still got the same error.  I verified that the package is installed in the correct version of pip with `pip list`.

Comment: Your problem description is unclear. What do you mean by "executing files in the terminal"? When you run python scripts in the terminal, is your anaconda environment active? If you print `sys.executable` in Spyder and in your terminal's python (`python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`), do you see the same python binary?

Comment: When I say "in the terminal," I just mean like `python myfile.py` without an Anaconda environment activated.  To your last question, in Spyder it's `/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` and in the terminal it's `/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/bin/python` so different files.  I added a link in the question to guide I followed to reinstall Python 3 after the macOS upgrade.  I think I might have done it differently in the previous macOS version.  Maybe that's causing the issue.

Comment: OK, the paths show that you are indeed using different python installations in the terminal and spyder. Therefore a package installed with pip in the terminal will not be visible in spyder and vice-versa. If you wish to use the same python environment in both, you need to activate anaconda python in the terminal as well. (Or configure spyder to use the terminal's python but you probably don't want that). In case you wish to set anaconda python as the default in the terminal, run `conda init`.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are using different Python installations in Spyder and terminal. Therefore packages installed with `pip` in the terminal will not be visible in Spyder and vice-versa. If you want to have access to the same packages in both, the best solution is to activate Anaconda Python (or its specific conda environment) in the terminal.

You can activate Anaconda automatically in the terminal by running `conda init` (it will include the activation commands to your `~/.bashrc` file).

Comment: Is there a way to either 1) make the terminal default to the Anaconda installation (without breaking anything) or 2) access the terminal installation from Spyder?  I'm mainly just trying save space at this point since some packages (e.g., tensorflow) are quite large.  I also run a few files from node child processes, but I edit/test them in Spyder, although I guess I can try activating Anaconda through the child processes.

Comment: I think what you want is to create a new conda environment in which you install both spyder and tensorflow. This way the tensorflow installation won't break your system Python. When you want to use tensorflow, first activate the conda environment in the terminal. If you want to use Spyder, you can launch it with the command `spyder`.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem before. I just share my solution. If you think this is not helpfull. You can leave a comment, then I can delete the answer.

Write in front, my solution give up the anaconda pip and default system pip. If you just want use anaconda. Then just read my solution as knowledge supplement or just skip my answer.

In my understanding, you need a way to control your python environment. Then you can build the same environment on any computer.

First, use anaconda manage the python version.

You can use

```
conda create --name python3.6 python=3.6
```

create specific python.

Then use

```
conda activate python3.6
```

to activate the specifaic version python3.6. You can add this to your .bashrc to auto activate the specfic version.

Second, install virtual environment management tool. I usually use pipenv. Install it by

```
pip install pipenv
```

Third, create virtual environment for your project.

```
cd your project folder
pipenv shell
pipenv install --skip-lock your package
```

Then you will can see it generate a pipfile under your project. If you keep it by upload your project to github or other way. Then you can build the virtual envriment any machine like this:

1. install conda.
2. activate specific version python and install pipenv.
3. git clone your project and cd into it.
4. pipenv shell
5. pipenv install --skip-lock.

Then you will get a same environment as the pipfile.